# How to avoid react date picker calendar to open on tab keypress from previous textbox

Tags: reactjs, keyboard-events, react-datepicker

We have installed react-datepicker component. The default behaviour is that the calendar is getting opened on tab keypress from previous field. How can I avoid this. Please suggest as I am unable to override the default behaviour of this component. I just want the focus to be on this control when tab is pressed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **preventOpenOnFocus** property

```
<DatePicker
  ...
  preventOpenOnFocus={true}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open it manually:

```
<DatePicker
   ref={(c) => this._calendar = c}
   locale='ru'
    ...
   customInput={<InputField {...this.props} calendar={this._calendar}/>}
/>
```

And then somewhere

```
this._calendar.setOpen(bool)
```

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddler example?